# MySQL Select where default is last resort

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I am trying to get a joined table and while ordering by one column and group by.  I'm trying to select the CUID starting with CU over the DEFAULT values.  I've read the answers posted on StackOverflow and it seems like I'm doing things correctly.  I think it might just be something small that I'm missing. I think that the order by doesn't work because of the insert order.  I would like to make a query to use DEFAULT as its last option.

```
SELECT A.*, B.value, B.CUID  
FROM A 
JOIN B 
ON A.ID = B.SettingID 
WHERE B.CUID = 'CU1' OR B.CUID = 'DEFAULT'
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY CUID ASC
```

After some help from a friend, found out that this would only work some of the time because of the insert order and only if the B.CUID is alphabetically after 'DEFAULT'.

Table A

```
| id   | Name  | 
|  1   |  blah |
|  2   |  was  | 
|  3   |  here |
```

Table B

```
| ID   | SettingID | Value | CUID    |
|  1   |  1        |  a    | CU1     |
|  2   |  2        |  b    | CU1     |
|  3   |  1        |  c    | DEFAULT |
|  4   |  2        |  d    | DEFAULT |
|  5   |  3        |  e    | DEFAULT |
```

Results without GROUP BY

```
|  SettingID | Name | Value | CUID    |
|    1       | blah |  a    | CU1     |
|    2       | was  |  b    | CU1     |
|    1       | blah |  c    | DEFAULT |
|    2       | was  |  d    | DEFAULT |
|    3       | here |  e    | DEFAULT |
```

Results after GROUP BY

```
|  SettingID | Name | Value | CUID    |
|    1       | blah |  c    | DEFAULT |
|    2       | was  |  d    | DEFAULT |
|    3       | here |  e    | DEFAULT |
```

Expected results

```
|  SettingID | Name | Value | CUID    |
|    1       | blah |  a    | CU1     |
|    2       | was  |  b    | CU1     |
|    3       | here |  e    | DEFAULT |
```

Comment: The query is incorrect. See ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql mode descriprion.

Comment: @Akina The query works just fine for me.

Comment: *The query works just fine for me.* "Works fine" and "gives unexpected result" are not compatible. And about the query. There are `Value` values `'a'` and `'c'` for `SettingID=1` in your data. After grouping server must return one single value. You have not specified what must be returned (first-last-greatest-least-etc.). Server returns one random from them - and this is correct for it. Anything that is not explicitly described can be anything. You need in some definite value? if so then your query does not match your need - i.e. it is incorrect.

Comment: @akina Sorry, i updated my question so that it is more specific.  The table can have a DEFAULT setting and any other CUID Setting.  There will only be one other.  Example when there is a DEFAULT and a CUID = BLAH.  I would like to grab the row with BLAH.  I would like DEFAULT to be the secondary option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `EXISTS`, so that for each `SettingID` you get the row with `CUID` that starts with `'CU'` or if it does not exist then you get the row with the alternative value:

```
SELECT a.*, b.value, b.CUID 
FROM TableA a 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b1.*
  FROM TableB b1
  WHERE b1.CUID LIKE 'CU%'
     OR NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM TableB b2
       WHERE b2.SettingID = b1.SettingID AND b2.CUID LIKE 'CU%'
     )
) b ON b.SettingID = a.id
```

If your version of MySql is 8.0+, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function in the table `TableB` to get the preferred row:

```
SELECT a.*, b.value, b.CUID 
FROM TableA a 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SettingID ORDER BY CUID LIKE 'CU%' DESC) rn
  FROM TableB
) b ON b.SettingID = a.id
WHERE b.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e8abd6bc73a068a3a9d750ee6db9f826).

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  All I needed to do was change the 'CU%' to the actual value I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The table can have a DEFAULT setting and any other CUID Setting. There will only be one other.

I'd use

```sql
SELECT b1.SettingID, 
       a.name,
       COALESCE(b2.value, b1.value) AS value,
       COALESCE(b2.CUID, b1.CUID) AS CUID
FROM a
JOIN b AS b1 on a.id = b1.SettingID
LEFT JOIN b AS b2 ON a.id = b2.SettingID 
                 AND b2.CUID != 'DEFAULT'
WHERE b1.CUID = 'DEFAULT'
```

If there may be more than one `'DEFAULT'` per `SettingID` then add `DISTINCT`.

Comment: This does not give me any defaults.  The results is settingID 1 and 2 only

Comment: @SariRahal oops.. sorry. Fixed.

Comment: I originally implemented the answer above.  and months later circled around to using this one as well.  All I needed to do was updated your !='DEFAULT' to = CUID. Both work well.  Thank you.